# After calling sign_in in RegistrationsController the subsequent request gets 403 on require_current_user filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I work on json API Rails app and use Devise authentication.

In `RegistrationsController#create` after an user is created I call `sign_in(resource_name, resource)`. As I see in Firebug the API server returns a cookie `_app_session` with encrypted session data.

```
def create
  sign_out
  build_resource

  if resource.save
    sign_in resource_name, resource

    hash = {
      :last_profile => resource.last_profile,
      :settings     => current_user.owner_hash
    } # it contains actual values for not nil current_user

    render json: hash  
  else
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    render status: 403, json: resource.errors
  end
end
```

Then on subsequent API request `require_current_user` filter triggers, despite I see right the same cookie in the request.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def require_current_user
    return if current_user
    render :status => 403, :text => I18n.t("errors.messages.login_required")
  end
  # ...
end
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by  `subsequent API request`? Are you trying to create another user? When is `require_current_user` triggered?

Comment: The subsequent API request is `POST /me/avatar` which triggers  `require_current_user` filter

Comment: require_current_user returning 403 implies your forbidden access. The user session isn't being created or is destroyed somewhere along that method chain.

Comment: Can you come on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror as SO doesn't like lengthy discussions in the comments.

Comment: I see in debugger that session exists in `:create` action, but is an empty hash in `:require_current_user` action. How can I find the code which destroys the session? When it is created and how does it survive in between requests?